# Concatenate arrays across column in Greenplum

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greenplum

I am trying to aggregate the arrays present in column 'agg' grouping them by product and get the all the events from the last 13 weeks.

for example : the first row value of aggregation should be like : aggregate all the arrays grouping them by product and pick up only the last 13week data. that is from 2/8/2014 to last_13(last 13 week date taking 2/8/2014 as the reference which is 11-10-2013)

I tried the following way but does not work .

```
select array_cat(a.agg2) over(partition by a.PName order by a.PName ,a.week_date desc rows between 0 preceding and 13 following)
    from (
    select PName,week_date,array_agg(raw_value)  agg2,
    from vin_temp_table group by PName,week_date order by PName,week_date desc
    )a
```

EDIT :

query :

```
select PName,week_date,array_agg(raw_value)  agg,
        from vin_temp_table group by PName,week_date order by PName,week_date desc
```

results in the following data

```
PName       week_date              agg
5773    2/8/2014    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5773    2/1/2014    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5773    1/25/2014   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5774    1/18/2014   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5775    1/11/2014   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5776    12/28/2013  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5776    12/21/2013  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5776    12/14/2013  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5776    12/7/2013   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5777    11/30/2013  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5778    11/16/2013      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5778    11/9/2013   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
5778    11/2/2013   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Raw data :  `select * from vin_temp_table`

```
 Pname       week_date       raw_value
    5773    10/21/2006  0
    5773    10/28/2006  0
    5773    11/18/2006  0
    5773    11/18/2006  0
    5773    1/20/2007   0
    5773    5/12/2007   0
    5773    7/21/2007   0
    5773    7/21/2007   0
    5773    8/11/2007   0
    5773    8/25/2007   0
    5773    9/1/2007    0
```

I even tried to partitioning using array_agg on Pname and week_date. But was not successful with this one too as the Greenplum version 8.2 was not supporting it.

Could some one help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: Please show some sample data, preferably as `create table` and `insert` statements. Right now I see the query and the "wrong" output, but not the *expected* output or the input data.

Comment: Also, you say postgresql 8.2 in text, and use tags for 9.1 and 8.4. WTF? What *exactly* are you using? Show `SELECT version()`. And don't just add random tags.

Comment: its postgres 8.2.15 (Green plum). I dont have postgres 8.2 tag in stack overflow so I have tagged in latest versions. Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: I have edited my post to include more details now. Thanks

Comment: Argh. Greenplum is not PostgreSQL. It's a heavily modified fork of an old PostgreSQL version. If you're using Greenplum, say so. (I don't have access to Greenplum, so I can't help you with this).